# (QtCreator)Как скомпилировать программу для WIndows из под Linux?

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, mingw, archlinux

Я пользуюсь Arch Linux и в QtCreator, сделал простой калькулятор с интерфейсом и решил попробовать собрать его для другой ОС. У меня уже получалось собрать простой код C++ на Linux с помощью MinGW и успешно запустить его на Windows. Но должного совета по кросс-компиляции(если этот термин здесь уместен) я не нашёл.

В настройках QtCreator пытался добавить Kit и поставить в нём компилятор MinGW но вылезло сообщение что MinGW не будет работать с этой версией Qt. Похоже нужна какая-то особенная версия Qt под MinGW но где её достать, а тем более как её установить я не знаю.

Comment: [How do I configure Qt for cross-compilation from Linux to Windows target?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467983)

Comment: Под вайном компилируется с меньшей головной болью чем с использованием кросскомпилятора.

Comment: @eri А в чём головная боль установить из реп кросс-версии mingw и qt и выполнить в консоли пару команд?

Comment: Вот ещё инструкция: [Cross-Compiling Windows Applications in Linux with MXE](https://blog.8bitbuddhism.com/2018/08/22/cross-compiling-windows-applications-with-mxe/) (особое внимание обратите на комментарии к ней, если требуется хорошая интеграция с QtCreator).

Comment: Ну началось с того что мингв начал компилировать кутэ - больше 6 часов и пара десятков гигабайт объектных файлов) сейчас может ктото положил актуальную кутэ в аур, но год назад попалось, что версия отдичалась от системной. Дождался я сборки и пошел запускать экзешник на винде - а он не стартанул) скачал я установщик виндовый, установил сдк и за 5 минут получил прогу с инсталятором

Comment: @eri Судя по логу в [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/log/?h=mingw-w64-qt5-base-static) там Qt постоянно обновляется до актуальной версии. Может и с лагом в какую неделю от официального релиза, но как по мне, это не критично.